# get wrong position in recyclerview which in fragment with viewpager

Tags: android-fragments, caching, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a viewpager with 4 Fragment, there are a RecyclerView and SwipeRefreshLayout in each Fragment. xml code like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/orderList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

When I switch ViewPager from left to right, I get the RecyclerView in Fragment like

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            //set swipeRefreshWidget can not refresh when recyclerView is not in the top
            mSwipeRefreshWidget.setEnabled(orderLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

But when I switch viewpager from page A to page B and to page C ,when in the page C, the recyclerView is not in the top(findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition is not 0),but at that time ,I can not get the findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition when switch to page C ,so the swipeRefreshWidget can refresh , but I want it can not refresh.
like this.
PS.the recyclerView in page B is in the top,but in page A and page C,recyclerView is in the middle.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problems. first page display the second pages' content.
Because i set:
static string week; 
and week belongs to class. when i return new Fragment()
twice. the first fragment.week had changed. the result is first.week == second.week.
also because FragmentStatePagerAdapter will Execute getitem() twice. so the content of first pager is wrong. he will display second fragment's content in first page.